# Linker Error in Xcode 8.1 when trying to build UETorch

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, linker, unreal-engine4

I've been trying to build UETorch for OSX 10.12 using Xcode and have encountered the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FlushRenderingCommands()", referenced from:
      _CaptureScreenshot in Module.UETorch.cpp.o
      InitCapture(UObject*, IntSize const*, FViewport**, APlayerController**, UWorld**, FSceneView**) in Module.UETorch.cpp.o
  "FSlateApplication::CurrentApplication", referenced from:
      _CaptureScreenshot in Module.UETorch.cpp.o
      FSlateApplication::Get() in Module.UETorch.cpp.o
  "FSlateApplication::TakeScreenshot(TSharedRef<SWidget, (ESPMode)0> const&, FIntRect const&, TArray<FColor, FDefaultAllocator>&, FIntVector&)", referenced from:
      _CaptureScreenshot in Module.UETorch.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems like the `ld: symbol(s) not found...` part is often fixed by using libstdc++ instead of libc++ and I have tried adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` to "Other Linker Flags" as well as linking libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib in the Build Phases section but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment hence adding it here, you get undefined symbols when you try to use the symbol/Call the function and the linker can not find its definition. So if the definition is from some library then add it during your linking stage. 
You can check if the definition is present or not in the library by using nm command, e.g. "nm -D"

Comment: The definition is in another part of the project (the UE4 source code rather than the UETorch plugin). I tried including it at the top of this file but that didn't seem to work... Where do you suggest I try running "nm -D"? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Top of the file would help during compilation, but you are getting a linker error, so the problem is during linking stage. You need to provide a library or use an object file, if you have the source.
First you need to find the library that has the definition, you can confirm the library has the definition by using "nm -D xxx.so | grep FlushRenderingCommands" to ascertain.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I can find the definition for FlushRenderingCommands in a .cpp file elsewhere in the project but I don't know where the generated object files go and why they wouldn't be linking properly... It seems like functions from other parts of the project are linking ok which is odd.

Comment: Ok, few things to take care

Comment: 1) So as the definition is in CPP file then you don't have mangling issues.
2) Now you can force compile that file and check where the object is getting created, or just read through your make file. And check if any library includes the object file during the libraries' creation.
3) And in during the creation of your project (executable file) you have to ensure to include the object file created or the library that has the object file.
Just keep trying, keep on googling or refer your study materials, you will resolve the issue soon, Best of Luck.